# Extract url from string using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like `"test http://www.bing.com test"`. I want to extract just the url (`"http://www.bing.com"`) from this string. How do I go about doing it? How would the regex look like?

Comment: And you really couldn't find a regex with a search for "regex match url" or something similar ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
((?:https?://)?www\.\S+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/uI3qL5/3)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Fede, i actually need a regex which would match without http as well. like just www.bing.com

Comment: @AnoojNair Ok, you can use this one instead. I've updated the answer with it: http://regex101.com/r/uI3qL5/2

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice URl parsing plug-in for jQuery you can use that will clean up the source text a bit before doing it's job.

https://github.com/websanova/js-url